# How to call variable incrementation with QAction without creating function

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, pyqt4

I have an action in QWidget which should increase the variable by one.

```
self.increase_video_step_action = QtGui.QAction('increase video step', self)
self.increase_video_step_action.triggered.connect(self.increment_video_step_action)

def increment_video_step(self):
     self.video_step += 1
```

This is an obvious solution which works. I just wonder whether there is a solution using lambda to do this without creating "redundant" method. If yes, how should it look like?

This won't work:

```
.connect(lambda x: self.video_step += 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with `setattr`:

```
connect(lambda x: setattr(self, 'video_step', self.video_step + 1))
```